# What's the term for a program or system that is used to maintain itself?

Tags: computer-science

And I don't mean **skynet**.  I'm thinking of say a compiler application that is used to compile itself, a VCS that tracks its own source code etc.

Answer (score 9):

The common term, especially for compilers, is "**[self-hosted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting)**".

Answer (score 4):

- Bootstrap: indicates that a new language compiler is mature enough to compile itself.  Usually used as a milestone.
- Dogfooding: used to indicate that the group responsible for development/delivery of a product use their own product.  Usually used as an endorsement.
- Self-hosted: software tool that is developed using the tool itself. Used to indicate status or state, i.e. having all the features to support running itself. Indicates robustness.
- Self-healing: Able to affect repair without the need to rely on outside resources. Indication of stability
- Auto-correcting: Able to make changes autonomously usually through various feedback mechanisms. Related to self-healing but not limited solely to repair of damage but also control of behavior.

Comment: +1 for Bootstrapping, though I think self-hosted is more generic.

Comment: Bootstrapping refers more specifically to the process of producing an initial self-hosted version (again, especially for compilers). Future versions are still self-hosted, but not really bootstrapped.

Answer (score 1):

It could be considered [dogfooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_one%27s_own_dog_food) - just a special case where you are not only using your tool, but using the tool to maintain itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of whole Programming Systems: [*Self-Sustaining System (S3)*](http://SWA.HPI.Uni-Potsdam.De/s3/) or *Self-Supporting System*.

But for the context you describe (VCS, compiler), the term *self-hosting* is generally used.

Answer (score 0):

"Reflective" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Self-Aware, Self-Programming...